# Помогите с отладкой составления логических условий

Tags: python, python-3.x, while

Делаю игру. Когда ответ "да", "Да", "нет" или "Нет" все равно выполняется первая часть цикла while

```
...
C_ans = input("Открыть сундук? ")
while C_ans != "Да" or C_ans != "да" or C_ans != "Нет" or C_ans != "нет":
    C_ans = input("Открыть сундук? ")
else:
    ...
```

Comment: Вроде все правильно, используйте И вместо ИЛИ

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы запрашивать ввод от пользователя до тех пор пока не вернётся ожидаемый ответ с точностью до регистра букв:

```
def ask(question, answers):
    while True:
        answer = input(question).casefold()
        if answer in answers:
            return answer
```

Пример:

```
answer = ask("Открыть сундук? ", ("да", "нет"))
```

Answer (score 0):

перевожу на русский то что вы делаете:

пока с_ans не равно "Да" или не равно "да" или не равно "Нет" или не равно "нет"

```
 C_ans = input("Открыть сундук? ") 
 while True:
     if  C_ans != "Да" or C_ans != "да" or C_ans != "Нет" or C_ans != "нет":
         C_ans = input("Открыть сундук? ")
     else:
         ...//ваши действия если введено "да,нет,Да,Нет"
```

Comment: Это не столь важно. Я имею ввиду что Даже когда я ввожу "да,нет,Да,Нет" выполняется первая часть цикла, хотя должна выполнятся вторая

Comment: не должна, у вас else есть а if  нет.С чего ей вдруг выполняться? В помощь https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/2.6.php

Comment: Так там же есть while

Comment: и что? while это цикл,а не условная конструкция .Перейдите по ссылке и прочитайте туториал,там все написано просто и понятно

Comment: Оба стейтмента циклов питон, предусматривают альтернативное поведение через `else:`.

Answer (score 0):

```
answer = input("Открыть сундук? ").lower()
while answer in ('да', 'нет'):
    answer = input("Открыть сундук? ").lower()
```

Comment: Извините, но все равно не работает(((

Answer (score 0):

```
while 1:
    answer = input("Открыть сундук? ").lower()
    if answer == "да":
        print("Сундук открыт")
    elif answer == "нет":
        print("Ну и дура")
    else:
        print("Game over")
        break
```